# Keyboard shortcut for comment blocks /* ... */ in Xcode

Tags: xcode, comments

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to comment out a selection of code. I already know about <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to add `//` in front of selected lines of code, but I want to be able to create `/* ... */` comment blocks this way.

The reason I want a shortcut for `/* ... */` is to be able to fold the comment blocks, which as far as I know you cannot do with the `//` comments.

So either I need a way to fold `//` type comments or a keyboard shortcut to create `/* ... */` comments

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a third-party text entry utility like Keyboard Maestro or Typinator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't as good as I'd like it to be, but this is the best option I've come up with so far.  I created a few custom code snippets in Xcode, each of which replaces a shortcut with an appropriately sized comment block.

For example, I have it replace the shortcut "com1" with an 80-character-wide comment block (for non-indented lines).  That's the following code in the Snippet Library in Xcode:

```
/*******************************************************************************
<#comment#>
******************************************************************************/
```

For indented lines, I have shortcuts "com2", "com3", and "com4", which are 76, 72, and 68 characters wide (respectively).

======

Also, Xcode's documentation isn't that helpful when it comes to code snippets.  To create a new code snippet, show the Utilities view (the pane on the right) and select the `{}` icon towards the bottom to show the Code Snippet Library.  Select some code to add, and drag it over to the Code Snippet Library (by left-clicking and **holding for a second** and then dragging - as a Windows user it took me far too long to figure this out).  This will create a new entry titled `My Code Snippet` at the very bottom of the Code Snippet Library, which you can mouse over and `Edit` to your liking.

======

EDIT: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm8gyrav0l9n6tb/MB_codesnippets.zip) I have uploaded a zip file containing five code snippets.  Levels 1 through 4 (com1, com2, com3, com4) are 80, 76, 72, and 68 characters wide, respectively.  Level 0 is a single line comment block that does not automatically format width (I use it for single comments to maintain formatting).

EDIT 2: Also, user code snippets are stored in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/`.

Comment: +1 This is an awesome answer. But really..this is the state of xcode? There are free text editors that do this.

Answer (score 2):

i reposted your question on apple dev forums .... i am also looking for the answer. here is a response i got ..... havent tried to do it yet but will soon.

in the WWDC 2012 video Session 402 - Working Efficiently with Xcode ( from around 6 minutes in) there's a description of how to use the Mac OSX Automator to add a service to manipulate selected text. The example shown in the video is to remove duplicates in a selection of text using the shell commands sort and uniq. Using this approach you could shell out to an awk

awk 'BEGIN{print "/*"}{print $0}END{print "*/"}'

which will, for any given selected text, put the comment delimiters before and after. Then add a shortcut to invoke this service.

Comment: It works almost perfect. But I shortcut is not handled in Xcode. For example I asign cmd+shift+a shortcat - it works everywhere, but not in Xcode. Do you know why?